# Expand navigation property of owned type OData EF Core

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, odata

I have the following entities:

```
[Table("tblA")]
public class EntityA
{
    [Key]
    public int ID { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public virtual EntityB EntityB { get; set; }
}

[Owned]
public class EntityB
{   
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public string Description { get; set; }

    public virtual EntityD EntityD { get; set; }
}

[Table("tblD")]
public class EntityD
{
    [Key]
    public int ID { get; set; }

    public int Count { get; set; }
}
```

And I want to retrieve EntityA including EntityD using OData. I've tried the following request but it didn't work: https://localhost:7249/EntityA?$expand=EntityD and returned error message:

```
"message": "The query specified in the URI is not valid. Could not find a property named 'EntityD' on type 'EntityA'.",
```

Answer (score 0):

You still need expand twice,I tried as below:

```
https://localhost:xxxx/odata/EntityA?$expand=EntityB($expand=EntityD)
```

Regist the service:

```
var modelBuilder = new ODataConventionModelBuilder();
modelBuilder.EntityType<EntityD>();
modelBuilder.EntityType<EntityB>();
modelBuilder.EntitySet<EntityA>("EntityA");

builder.Services.AddControllers().AddOData(
    options => options.Select().Filter().OrderBy().Expand().Count().SetMaxTop(null).AddRouteComponents(
        "odata",
        modelBuilder.GetEdmModel()));
```

Result:

[image]